# Vba/Macro to paste in next available row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste certain cells that are not in the same column or row and paste them in Specific columns (it will be the same columns everytime). Once each entry is done, I want the next set of entries to paste on the next available row. The first set of code for Paste_NextRow() was ran as a macro and this was the code that was returned. The ranges I selected have formulas in them that will have different values each month. I am pasting them in a row with headers in row A. The second set of code for LastRow() I found this online and it will return the last row that is empty. I'm unsure how to utilize the second set of code to paste in the next available row. If you need additional context in order to help modify the code please let me know. Thanks. I've edited the text to show the code accordingly.

```
Sub Paste_NextRow()  
'  
' Paste_NextRow Macro  
'

'

    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Select  
    Range("F3").Select  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Select  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  
    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Select  
    Range("F2").Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Select  
    Range("C2").Select  
     Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  
     Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Select  
    Range("B4").Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Select  
    Range("B2").Select  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  
    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Select  
    Range("F4").Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Select  
    Range("D2").Select  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  
    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Select  
    Range("F5").Select  
    Application.CutCopyMode = False  
    Selection.Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Select  
    Range("E2").Select  
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  
    Range("A3").Select  
End Sub  

Sub LastRow()  
    NextRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Number").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Code is text and it should be added here as such. You can indent it with 4 spaces (or a tab in an external editor) so it is formatted as code. Or you can copy and paste as-is, highlight the code, and hit the little `{}` button at the top of the text editor. It's unlikely that anyone here will transcribe your code back into text to help solve this one.

Comment: Looking at your code, my best guess is that you can change all of ranges that you select to PASTE into from `Range("B2").Select` over to `Range("B" & LastRow).Select` and let 'er rip. Honestly though, if we can get a text version of this code, I think there are a lot of areas for improvement.

Comment: Hi JNevill I've updated the post to text. First time posting, didn't think that through.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for updating!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick rewrite setting a variable (called `lastRow`) to the last row in your `invoice number` tab.

```
Sub Paste_NextRow()  
'  
' Paste_NextRow Macro  
'

'
    'Get the last used row into a variable
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Number").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Copy Summary Data Sheet F3
    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F3").Copy 

    'And paste it into the last row (column F) of Invoice Number sheet
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("F" & LastRow).Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  

    'Use similar logic for the remaining cells
    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F2").Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("C" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  

    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("B4").Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("B" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  

    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F4").Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("D" & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False 

    Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F5").Copy  
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("E"  & lastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _  
        :=False, Transpose:=False  

End Sub
```

You'll see that there are no `.Select` happening here since Selecting a sheet or a cell is something a human does. There really isn't a need to do that in VBA where instead we can just specify exactly what we want to copy and where we want to paste it.

While this is cleaned up, it's still a little cumbersome to just copy and paste VALUES around the workbook. It uses the clipboard and has multiple statements for each copy/paste.

Instead we can just set the value of one cell equal to the value of another cell:

```
Sub Paste_NextRow()  
'  
' Paste_NextRow Macro  
'

'
    'Get the last used row into a variable
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Number").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("F" & LastRow).Value = Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F3").value
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("C" & lastRow).value = Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F2").value 
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("B" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("B4").value
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("D" & lastRow).Value = Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F4").value 
    Sheets("Invoice Number").Range("E"  & lastRow).Value = Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET").Range("F5").value

End Sub
```

Lastly, typing out those worksheet names over and over again is cumbersome. We can use a couple of variables to hold the two worksheets we care about. This is nice if you ever want to change worksheet names as you only have one place in the code to make the change:

```
Sub Paste_NextRow()  
'  
' Paste_NextRow Macro  
'

'
    'Set some variables to hold our worksheets
    Dim wsCopy as Worksheet
    Dim wsPaste as Worksheet

    Set wsCopy = Sheets("SUMMARY DATA SHEET")
    Set wsPaste = Sheets("Invoice Number")

    'Get the last used row into a variable
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice Number").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Copy values over
    wsPaste.Range("F" & LastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("F3").value
    wsPaste.Range("C" & lastRow).value = wsCopy.Range("F2").value 
    wsPaste.Range("B" & lastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("B4").value
    wsPaste.Range("D" & lastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("F4").value 
    wsPaste.Range("E" & lastRow).Value = wsCopy.Range("F5").value

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! What would you recommend to learn more about VBA? Most of my knowledge of it is from copying others work and customizing it to my needs rather than being able to build my own.